# Implicit static variable in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, static-members

I have an object SeatSelection. In this object, I declare a array of integer arrays as follows

```
int *rows[25];
```

My SeatSelection constructor initializes the rows variable as follows:

```
SeatSelection::SeatSelection(int start, int range){
  this->range = range;
  this->start = start;

  for(int i = 0; i < range; i++){
    rows[i] = new int[10];

  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    rows[i][j] = (j+1);
  }
}
```

In theory, I should now have an array of integer arrays of size 10 right?

In my driver class,

I am declaring two SeatSelection objects, both with different paramaters:

```
SeatSelection premium(1,5);
SeatSelection regular(6, 15);
```

`premium` should have 5 rows of 10 seats each = 50 seats.

`regular` should have 15 rows of 10 seats each = 150 seats.

Through some debugging, I found out that both these distinct SeatSelection objects are sharing the same `rows` pointer/array. I did not declare this variable as static. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you consider `std::vector` ?

Comment: Debug output and an SSCCE or it didn't happen.

Comment: This is for an assignment where we are not allowed to use `std::vector`. Our arrays must be done "by hand."

Comment: where did you declare it? Is it global? There is no context around `int *rows[25]`

Comment: @JohnDibling, I'm not entirely sure how I can provide my debugging session? Did you want a copy of my sources, breakpoints, and screenshot of my gdb session?

Comment: The fact you're not initializing `rows` in the constructor makes me think it could be a global.  How and where is it declared?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue from the code you have posted http://ideone.com/m8Z2CJ

Comment: @OmarDarwish:  No.  I want you to build an SSCCE that demonstrates the same problem.  20 lines of code ought to do it.

Comment: It was declared outside of the `SeatSelection::` scope so I think that would make it a global variable? http://pastebin.com/0b3rSyB7

Comment: @OmarDarwish:  If you don't know what SSCCE is:  http://sscce.org/

Comment: @OmarDarwish that would be global. You want to declare it in the class declaration in the header file

Comment: @OmarDarwish:  Oh, yes.  That's a global.

Comment: It's quite disconcerting how simplistic and wrong is the meaning of `static` taught to so many students today.

Comment: Declared `*rows[25]` as a private member in `SeatSelection.h` and that seems to have solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Here's something that will blow your mind.  Since `rows` was a global, it actually *did* have implicit `static` lifetime!

Comment: Don't forget deallocate rows in SeatSelection::~SeatSelection

Comment: @JohnDibling that is pretty useful to know! I think I've been spoiled by the Java garbage collector. Slowly trudging up this C++ learning curve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a separate `rows` variable for each class instance, it's not sufficient to make the variable "not `static`".

You have to make it a class member to give it per-instance storage.

Other non-static variables have the storage duration determined by their scope.  A non-static namespace-member (including the global namespace) variable has one copy for the entire program.  A non-static local variable has one copy per invocation of the function.

Comment: @John: Agreed.  Your crystal ball worked quite well for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like int *row[25] are not part of SeatSelection class. You may have row[] array locally / globally declared and each of SeatSelection object is using same space. After premium object writes to row[] memory, regular object overwrites it.